# $\operatorname{Aut}(V)$ is isomorphic to $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm currently working my way through Harvard's online abstract algebra lectures (if you're interested, you can find them [here](http://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/abstract-algebra)).  The lectures come complete with notes and homework problems.  Of course, since I don't actually go to Harvard, I can't hand in the homework assignments to find out if I'm doing them correctly.  So I've decided to try to crowd source the grading of my solutions.  I'll post individual questions as I finish them and wait for comments.  I would like to get critiques of not just my reasoning but the style of my write ups as well.  Also, any alternative approaches to the problem would be welcome.  I've looked for forums dedicated to these kinds of OCW courses but have not been able to find any.  This surprises me.  It seems like, with the advent of these free online educational resources, an online meeting place for those who take advantage of them would be a natural offshoot.  So this might be a bit of an experiment.  Unless I'm the 873rd person to post something like this here.  If that's the case, sorry for being so long winded.

Anyway, on with the question.  This one is assigned in the 4th lecture.

> Let $V$ denote the Klein 4-group.  Show that $\operatorname{Aut}(V)$ is isomorphic to $S_3$.

(I've moved my solution below to keep this question from showing up in the unanswered list.)

Thanks...

Comment: Excellent. I like the general idea of "crowd sourcing" your solutions. By the way, another approach is to realize that the set of automorphisms is surely a subset of $S_3$, and so it suffices to find an automorphism of order 2 and one of order 3.

Comment: Thanks Steve.  If we can state from the beginning that Aut(V) is a subset of S$_3$, would it then be enough to say that the order of Aut(V) is 6 to prove it's isomorphic to S$_3$ without having to find the automorphisms?

Comment: @jobrien929Hi, I'm going through the same process. I am, however, using the 2nd edition. Do you have any suggestions as to how know what are the corresponding problems. Also, while I'm not very good at it, so I don't know what contribution I could make, if you set up a website or other mechanism, I would really appreciate being informed. Regards.

Comment: @Andrew  Nice to know I'm not doing this alone.  I can't be much help with figuring out which problems you should work on in the 2nd edition.  I can tell you that a few minutes with google and the keywords Artin, Algebra, and pdf would probably render the problem moot.  I won't be setting up a website or anything but I will be posting my work here so if you look up my postings you'll be seeing new problems appear.  I'm more than happy to discuss any of the assignments in the comments.  It's the whole reason I'm taking the time to post them.  Thanks.

Comment: @jobrien929: If I might make a suggestion: Your question shows up as "unanswered", and it will be periodically "bumped" automatically. Now that you are happy with your solution and it has been appropriately critiqued, I suggest that you remove your solution from the original post and post it as an answer instead. (Yes, you can answer your own questions, and even accept your own answer to your own question). Same for your other posts. Thank you.

Comment: @Arturo:  Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm new to this site and still figuring out the etiquette.

Comment: @jobrien929: No worries! That particular item is a bit obscure, even for people who are regulars.

Comment: @jobrien929: Just to clarify: this is a good thing to do once all the dust has settled; your original formatting of putting your answer in the original post is fine and a good way to get the discussion started.

Comment: @Steve DHi-I saw your comment. Would you please give me some help as to why it is easily apparent that the set of automorphisms is a subset of $S_3$. And then further, why is it sufficient to find just one automorphism of order 2 and one of order 3 vs. having the equivalent number as in $S_3$. (I've been looking at the V group as four diagonal matrices with + or - 1's) Thanks from a self-studier.

Comment: @Andrew: Every automorphism of $V$ will fix the identity, and will act as a permutation (injectively and surjectively) on the non-identity elements, of which there are $3$.  Thus the automorphism group can be treated as a subgroup of $S_3$.  Now consider what Lagrange's theorem says about the order of elements, and the order of the group that contains them.

Comment: @Steve DThanks I get it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is my answer.  Additional comments are always welcome.

Let $f:V\rightarrow V$ be a permutation that fixes the identity element.  By definition, this map is bijective.  $V$ has the property that the product of any 2 distinct non-identity elements is the 3rd non-identity element.  This implies $f(vv^\prime)=f(v)\cdot f(v^\prime)$ for all $v,v^\prime \in V$ with $v,v^\prime\neq e$.  For products involving the identity element, $f(ev)=f(e)\cdot f(v)=e\cdot f(v)=f(v)$ for all $v\in V$.  Also, since all non-identity elements of $V$ have order 2, $f(v^2)=f(vv)=f(v)\cdot f(v)=e$ for all $v\in V$.  Hence, any permutation of the elements of $V$ that fixes the identity element is an automorphism of $V$.  Since these permutations exhaust all possible automorphisms of $V$, they are the elements of Aut($V$).

Since the $3!=6$ elements of Aut($V$) represent all permutations of 3 objects, Aut($V$) is isomorphic to S$_3$.

Comment: The answer depends on the background that is assumed. If you have done integers mod $n$, then one can note that $V$ can be given the structure of a $2$-dimensional space over $\mathbf{Z}_{2}$, with group homomorphisms being automatically linear maps. Now note that any two nonzero, distinct elements are a basis...