# The inverse of a permutation matrix is its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, transpose, permutation-matrices

I do this exercise but I don't know if this okay.
$$P^{-1}_{\sigma}=P^{T}_{\sigma}=P_{\sigma^{-1}}$$ Where $P_{\sigma}=[e_{\sigma(1)},e_{\sigma(2)},...,e_{\sigma(n)}]$
The first thing that I do is proving that $$P^{-1}_{\sigma}=P^{T}_{\sigma}$$ And we got
$$P^{-1}_{\sigma}=[e_{\sigma(1)},e_{\sigma(2)},...,e_{\sigma(n)}]^{-1}=e_{\sigma(1)}^{-1},e_{\sigma(2)}^{-1},...,e_{\sigma(n)}^{-1}= e_{\sigma(n)},e_{\sigma(n-1)},...,e_{\sigma(1)}= [e_{\sigma(1)},e_{\sigma(2)},...,e_{\sigma(n)}]^{T}=P^{T}_{\sigma}$$
Now we prove that $$P^{-1}_{\sigma}=P_{\sigma^{-1}}$$
So we got
$$ P^{-1}_{\sigma}=[e_{\sigma(1)},e_{\sigma(2)},...,e_{\sigma(n)}]^{-1}=e_{\sigma(1)}^{-1},e_{\sigma(2)}^{-1},...,e_{\sigma(n)}^{-1}=e_{\sigma(1)^{-1}},e_{\sigma(2)^{-1}},...,e_{\sigma(n)^{-1}}=P_{\sigma^{-1}} $$
And after that we got $$P^{-1}_{\sigma}=P^{T}_{\sigma}=P_{\sigma^{-1}}$$

This is my solution and I want to know if is right. :)

Comment: What do you mean by the inverse of a vector, e.g., $e_{\sigma(1)}^{-1}$?

Comment: Maybe you want to show that $P_{\sigma\cdot\tau}=P_{\sigma}\times P_{\tau}$; that is, $P$ is a group morphism from $\mathfrak{S}_n$ to $\operatorname{GL}(n)$. Then, isn't $P_{\sigma^{-1}}=P_{\sigma}^{-1}$ obvious?

Comment: I think you should calculate $P_\sigma^TP_\sigma$ by hand, using the standard matrix multiplication formula. See what happens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The transpose of a permutation matrix is its inverse.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98549/the-transpose-of-a-permutation-matrix-is-its-inverse)

Comment: Permutation matrices are also *orthogonal matrices*, and more generally the inverse of an orthogonal matrix is its transpose.

Comment: adding to Gerry: A matrix is orthogonal iff its rows form an orthonormal basis. The rows of a permutation matrix are just the standard (orthonormal) basis.