# How to show $Ha\cap Hb=\emptyset$

Tags: abstract-algebra

My question is this.  I have
Let $H\le G, a,b\in G$  Define $Hx=\{hx|h\in H\}$  Show that $Ha=Hb$ or $Ha\cap Hb=\emptyset$.

I thought I would do a proof by contradiction.  So suppose that $Ha\cap Hb$ is nonempty.  Then there exists an element $x$ such that $x\in Ha$ and$ x\in Hb$ Thus we can write $x$ as
$$x=h_1a,\text{ and } x=h_2b$$
Then $h_1a=h_2b$ and thus $a=h_1^{-1}h_2b$.

This is where I'm getting stuck.
I just don't know how to go about showing that there exists a contradiction.

Comment: Show that $a\sim b \iff ab^{-1}\in H$ is an equivalence relation, and $Hb$ are the equivalence classes.

Comment: I like that method, but I'm trying to follow the book I'm working out of, and since equivalence relations are not covered until the next section, I want to use what I have done up to now...basically subgroups is the section the exercise is under...

Comment: Equivalence relations are very basic mathematicals objects. You might as well get used to using them.

Comment: there is an answer here... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737916/let-h-be-a-subgroup-of-g-and-let-a-and-b-belong-to-g-then-ah-bh-or?rq=1

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: Abstract Algebra by Herstein

Comment: Perhaps your problem is because there isn't a contradiction to be had! It is very possible for $Ha\cap Hb$ to be nonempty. You're not trying to prove that's impossible; you're trying to prove that it implies $Ha=Hb$.

Comment: Go from $a=h_1^{-1}h_2b\,$ to $\,Ha=Hb$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to proof that by contradiction, you have to assume that $Ha\cap Hb\notin\lbrace \emptyset, G \rbrace$.

Going on from where you got stuck:
$a=h_1^{-1}h_2b$ implies $Ha\subseteq Hb$ and multiplying from the left with $h_2^{-1}h_1$ gives $b=h_2^{-1}h_1a$ and therefore $Hb\subseteq Ha$. Combining the two inclusions gives $Ha=Hb$. Contradiction.