# a natural number m is obtained by rearranging the digits of another natural number n. Show that m − n must be divisible by 9.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

let **100a+10b+c = m** and **(100b+10c+a)=n**

**m-n = (100a+10b+c) - (100b+10c+a) = 99a-90b-9c**

its obvious that every such (m-n) will be divisible by 9. my question is : is there any theorem i could use to make this proof more presentable?

Comment: No, there is no need to use any "theorem". You should write $99a-90b-9c=9(11a-10b-c)$ to make it "obvious". Of course, what you have is not a full proof. It only concerns $3$-digit numbers.

Comment: A very useful, so to speak "theorem" is that _every natural number is congruent $\pmod 9$ with the sum of its digits_ (see the linked "duplicate": https://math.stackexchange.com/q/99725/700480). Which is not hard to prove (proof similar to the proof you would produce anyways) but it has a bonus (you see _why_ rearranging does not matter: because, for the plain sum of digits, the order of digits doesn't matter) and another bonus (immediately proves the criteria for divisibility by $3$ and $9$).