# If $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then for every $a,b$ there exists $x$ such that $x\equiv a \pmod m$ and $x\equiv b \pmod n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove the *Chinese Remainder Theorem*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99972/prove-the-chinese-remainder-theorem)

Suppose $gcd(m,  n) = 1$.  Show that for every pair of integers $a, b$, there exists an integer $x$ such that

$x \equiv a \pmod m$ and $x \equiv b \pmod n$

By $gcd$ I mean greatest common divisor.

Comment: See [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).